# SharePoint Designer 2013: WorkFlow status info: Show submitter's name

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I would like to ask you, how to setup WorkFlow in SharePoint Designer 2013 to show name of submitter in Status Info column?

Somehow i can't figure it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the submitter the same as Created by?

In this case you can use the action set value to value where the first value is status info and the second value is current item:created by

Comment: Couldn't find action like this. It's project workflow (project server)

Comment: 'Set value to value' is a standard action in SP designer workflow both for template 2010 and 2013